# Jquery change background dynamically not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following div:

```
<div class="bgslider">
</div>
```

I'm trying to change the background of the div dynamically when another element is receiving an event (for example over event).

The original css for bgslider class is:

```
.bgslider {
/*background: url(../img/slider/image1.jpg) no-repeat center top ;*/
background-image: url(../img/slider/image2.jpg);
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
min-height: 450px;
/*background-attachment: fixed;*/
display:block;
}
```

My javascript is the following:

```
$( ".slidermenu-li" ).hover(function( event ) {
    var image=$(this).data('img-src');
    var path="../img/slider/";
    var image_url_css='url('+path+image+');';
    $(".bgslider").css('background-image', image_url_css);

  });
```

The javascript is invoked and the image path is correct but on the browser the background image does not change.

Comment: What does `image_url` log as? Any errors in the console? Hint, hint...

Comment: `image_url_css` vs `image_url`...

Comment: You have a semi-colon as well here: `var image_url_css='url('+path+image+');';`. It should be `var image_url_css='url('+path+image+')';` The jQuery's css method requires only the **value** to be assigned to the property.

Comment: Sorry I paste the wrong code the variable image_url does not exist and in my code is right that is image_url_css. The problem was the semicolon at the end of image_url_css variable.

Comment: FYI, you are mis-using `hover()` in/out handler, `hover()` is different than `mouseover()` and in you case you should use `mouseenter` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the variable image_url_css was including also the semicolon but Jquery just need the value of the attribute. Now it's working.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a typo, you used `image_url` instead of `image_url_css`.

Try this:

```
$( ".slidermenu-li" ).hover(function( event ) {
    var image=$(this).data('img-src');
    var path="../img/slider/";
    var image_url_css='url('+path+image+');';
    $(".bgslider").css('background-image', image_url_css);

  });
```